# JavaScript code that runs returns "s" every second

Tags: javascript

I developed a clock, and I need a loop that returns "s" at every second

There is only one function in my program

I am lost in creating this loop, can you guys help me?

Comment: What did you try -- how are you lost?  The documentation seems clear to me.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: please add your code and some sort of output so we can understand better

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` :

```js
setInterval(() => {
    // your code
}, 1000); // 1000ms = 1second
```

You can read the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)